# Can Python directory names be keywords? E.g. 'import'?

Tags: python, module, keyword

Am I allowed to have a directory named 'import' containing Python code?  Or will the import command fail to parse it as a result?  Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) which accepts any string. Thus you may write:

```
__import__('keyword.submodule')
```

Comment: It's not. There are plenty of situations where the use of `__import__` may come in very handy. Bottomline is: there is no restriction on the module names in python. Whether or not it should be abused is another question.

Comment: @Olivier, I'm with @Mike on this one. `__import__` is there for when you know the module name at runtime. It was most certainly **not** intended to import a module called "import". `__import__('this')` rules! ;)

Comment: I'm using the pythondotnet library to import some .NET objects into my python scripts.  One of those namespaces is called `def` so without calling `__import__("def")` I would be unable to use them.  Agreed that best practice is to use the import keyword where possible (which should be most of the time) but there are scenarios that demand otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a directory with a name that is a Python keyword storing your Python code. This directory should not be used as a package, since package names should be valid Python identifiers.

Comment: @Olivier, I said "should". Python doesn't stop me from doing all sorts of awful things. I can use invalid identifiers as variables my modifying `globals()` or for attributes using `setattr` or plenty of other places, but fortunately I know better.

Comment: Your answer is misleading: you are saying that it's ok for a directory but not for a package to be a python keyword? I would say it's bad practice either way.

Comment: I don't see any reason to impose a naming convention on directories that don't end up having anything to do with the Python code they contain.

Answer (score 0):

> Or will the import command fail to parse it as a result?

It will indeed fail.